# URL encoded string in Requests POST

Tags: python, alchemyapi

I'm sure this is really banal and stupid but I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

I'm working with the Alchemy API, where the POST request using Requests looks like

```
r = requests.post(url, payload, headers=headers)
```

where payload is a dict with a field for url-encoded text like `text=this%20is%text`

The stupid problem I'm having is that if I use urllib for the encoding like `myText = urlencode({'text': textToEncode})`

I can't then insert it into the payload where `payload={'text': myText}` because then I get something probably like `text=text=this%20is%text`

This would be so much simpler if I could just encode the string itself. The encoding function adds this stuff I can't turn around an insert into the dict because the whole dict gets encoded.

Am I missing something incredibly simple and dumb?

Answer (score 1):

Try including the `Content-type` header, for example `application/json` and then using `data=json.dumps(payload)`.

```
import json
headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Comment: The api requires Content-Type header: application/x-www-form-urlencoded